# Kaminari if next page exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate, kaminari

What is the method in `kaminari` to know if next page exists? With `will_paginate` its simple you just call in `next_page?` on model. I wonder if there is anything in `kaminari`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To check if there is a next page in the kaminari views, use `current_page.next?`.

To query the @posts instead you can use `@posts.next_page` which will return nil if there is not a next page or `@posts.last_page?` which will be true if there is no next page.

Comment: what do I do for REST APIs?